# How to check the status of Ethernet port using ansible?

Tags: ansible, automation

I want to check status of Ethernet port whether it is up or down on remote server using Ansible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can connect to the machine (say, using a local connection), you can interrogate the [host facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables).

It should expose a list `ansible_interfaces`, which will include the name of your ethernet interface. Each device will have a key in the facts. If your device is called `eth0`, you will have a dict called `ansible_eth0`.

The keys should include:

```
"ansible_eth0" {
  "active": true,
  "device": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
      "address": "<address>",
      "broadcast": "<address>",
      "netmask": "<netmask>",
      "network": "<network>"
    },
    "ipv6": [
      {
        "address": "<ipv6_network>",
        "prefix": "64",
        "scope": "link"
      }
    ],
    "macaddress": "<hw_address>",
    "module": "<kernel_module>",
    "mtu": XXX,
    "pciid": "XXX",
    "promisc": false,
    "type": "ether"
}
```

The `active` key there will tell you whether the device is active.

I would do it in the following way:

- discover list of devices
- find device that matches a name
- discover status of the device.

A shorter way might be with a [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

If you need to check that the device is ready from a remote execution, you could use a [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) on a specific port that should become available when the device is up.

Comment: How would you do this after changing interface status. Example: ansible modified ifcfg-eth0 and restarted network service. What is the fastest way to verify the change did what it was supposed to?  It can run ansible_setup: again, but perhaps there is a faster way.

Comment: yes, the best way I think would be to refresh the facts, by running setup again. You could use a handler for setup and flush it when the relevant task changes.

Comment: Good idea. For my current project, I went with what I think is a faster, but less Ansible-ish method , if using the "ip" command in a shell task to get the status. Fr my project,I only need to shutdown some ports once, and after that they will never be used again.